# Video with autoplay in a Bootstrap modal with a stop when the modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I read a lot of similar posts but didn't find the right solution for my project.

I would like to let the user show/hide the bootstrap modal with a simple `<a>` balise. It's a Youtube iframe with an autoplay=1.

First problem is that when the page load, the video is launching and we can hear the sound but of course cannot see the video inside the bidding modal. Second problem, I need to stop the video when the user closes the modal with the cross or just by clicking outside the modal.

Here is a online demo : [See live demo](http://bp-design.fr/Redacteur/home.html)

Here is my code, I'm using Bootstrap 3+ :

```
<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade responsive-video" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>
```

and the JS :

```
<script>
  $('#myModal').on('show', function () {
    $('div.modal-body').html('<iframe width="100%" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PUcTN5ou2o0?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  });
  $('#myModal').on('hide', function () {
    $('div.modal-body').html('');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could leave the SRC attribute of the iframe blank initially and only set it to the desired YouTube video with autoplay=1 when the user opens the modal window.

HTML:

```
<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade responsive-video" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <iframe id="youtube" src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  $('#myModal').on('show', function () {
    $('div.modal-body iframe#youtube').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/PUcTN5ou2o0?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0');
  });
  $('#myModal').on('hide', function () {
    $('div.modal-body iframe#youtube').attr('src', '');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't comment, missing the privilege. So a quick answer with two possible solutions.

**Solution 1: use the Youtube API**

You can find the API reference here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

So you could create the iframe when showing the page and just use the `play()` method when launching the modal.

**Solution 2: use a premade player**

There are lots of good solutions out there. As I'm in the matter right now, I'd recommend using http://afterglowplayer.com (based on video.js) or some other similar solution. There is lightbox support and you don't have to cope with this kind of stuff. :)

Comment: Thanks i'll give a shot